# When I run "iotedge check" it yields a docker error

Tags: docker, arm, ubuntu-16.04, azure-iot-edge, banana-pi

I've installed iotedge on a banana pi device, which is running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS/armv7l.

When I run iotedge check, I get a result that indicates something's up with my docker installation. The output includes this statement,

> "docker: Error response from daemon: Could not check if docker-default
>   AppArmor profile was loaded: open
>   /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/profiles: no such file or directory."

When I tried to run a simple docker image ("docker run hello-world") afterwards, I got the same error.

I've been trying to load the docker-default profile myself, manually, but I'm at my limit in terms of understanding how to actually do that, and resolve this problem.

This is the result of running iotedge check:
[image: Log results from iotedge check - Configuration]

[image: log results from iotedge check - Connectivity]

Comment: did you follow these steps to install the container runtime? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux-arm#install-the-container-runtime If not, why not? If so, did you get errors?

Comment: Yep. I updated the question with the log results.

Comment: Noting here that the advice _seems_ to be, switch from ubuntu/arm to something else, https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?t=31369